# Show already hidden content on select

Tags: jquery

Okay, I have basic divs already being hidden through jquery and when the anchor link is clicked the hidden div is active and slides into view the other divs are hidden. The question is:

I have used Chris Coyiers (of CSS Tricks) [method of changing a menu to a drop down menu](http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/) depending on window size/screen size. Problem is it doesn't work on anchor links and I have tried .change, tried to manipulate window.location and even document.location (just checking) but I don't even understand why it doesn't work completely so I'm just a chicken with her head cut off.

I thought maybe I should try putting document.html#Id as the href and then maybe it would work but Nope.I looked at a lot of similar questions of here. But I cant seem to adapt them effectively to my needs.

As you can see I'm totally green. But HELP is so appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you have on jsfiddle.com

Comment: Oh dang, it's jsfiddle.net, not jsfiddle.com. So sorry.

Comment: Sure Thanks for helping. [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/PhatGirlTech/mesdM/) You'll see that clicking the links reveals another section but using the select does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a hidden element, give the element an ID and specify the jQuery/CSS-type selector for and ID as the value, like `#id`. Then change the javascript to show instead of redirect. Here is a jFiddle I wrote that does what you asked:

http://jsfiddle.net/mike_marcacci/jvSSa/

Note that I also capture link clicks, so that it works on both mobile and desktop versions:

```
function showSection(id){
    // hide already visible sections
    $('.hidden').css('display','');

    // show selected section
    $(id).css('display','block');
}

//make the select work
$("nav select").change(function() {
    showSection($(this).find("option:selected").val());
});

// make links work too
$("nav a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showSection(this.hash);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. I had to change my css but at least thats working so thanks a lot!

Comment: Your not gonna believe this because I barely do but I was having trouble with that script on other parts of the site aaaannnnd I really wanted the drop down to work the same way as my click buttons sooo, I looked at what I had and looked at what you gave and created a script in my old one that just works! [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhatGirlTech/GyPMF/1/)

Comment: Awesome! So glad I could help :-)